# Isolated Explorer Tool for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Anybody knows how to use Isolated Storage tool for Windows Phone 8.1 WITHOUT using Command with ISETool.exe.

Some previous Isolated Storage Tools like IsoSpy, ISE, Windows Phone Power Tools that works with GUI are very user friendly while coding.

Are there any tools available like them?

Answer (score 6):

[IsoStoreSpy](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) has been recently updated to support Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

No,windows provides only these 3 non command-line tools.

[IsoStoreSpy](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/downloads/get/835310) is best tool that i have ever used.you can use it without visual studio.just you need windows 8 OS and xap installed on device/emulator.